# import sysdig data into elastic

Tags: logstash

I am using the logstash config file that I got from this article...

http://logz.io/blog/sysdig-elk-stack/

The contents of /etc/logstash/sysdig-logstash.conf

```
input {
   stdin { }
}

filter {
      grok {
      pattern =&gt; "^%{NUMBER:num:int} %{NUMBER:time:float} %{INT:cpu:int} %{NOTSPACE:procname} %{NOTSPACE:tid} (?&lt;direction&gt;[&lt;&gt;]) %{WORD:event} %{DATA:args}$"
   }

date {
   match =&gt; [ "time", "UNIX" ]
}

   if [args] {
      kv {
         source =&gt; "args"
         remove_field =&gt; "args"
      }
   }
}

output {
   #stdout { codec =&gt; rubydebug }
   elasticsearch {
      }
}
```

When I try to dump the data into elastic using logstash, I get an error...

```
# sysdig -t a "not(proc.name = sysdig)" | bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/sysdig-logstash.conf
```

fetched an invalid config

What is the correct config file for processing sysdig data?

---

Update:

After correcting the => I can log the text to elastic. But with one problem. The entire log line got saved as a message field ignoring the grok pattern mentioned in the config file. For e.g. this is the output when I enabled stdout to rubydebug.

```
{
       "message" => "1894246 1478069107.694757379 1 sysdig (16910) > switch next=0 pgft_maj=0 pgft_min=1658 vm_size=97364 vm_rss=7816 vm_swap=0 ",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-11-02T06:45:07.725Z",
          "host" => "ip-172-31-0-192",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_grokparsefailure"
    ]
}
```

The article mentions separate fields for cpu, procname etc.

Comment: Make sure to replace all occurences of `=&gt;` with `=>`

Comment: I do not get an error after changing this to => but I still do not get the fields correctly processed in elastic. In other words, grok filter is not applied and the entire line shows up in the "message" field.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to specify the grok filter is like this, i.e. using `match` not `pattern`

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => {"message" => "^%{NUMBER:num:int} %{NUMBER:time:float} %{INT:cpu:int} %{NOTSPACE:procname} %{NOTSPACE:tid} (?&lt;direction&gt;[&lt;&gt;]) %{WORD:event} %{DATA:args}$" }
  }
}
```

Comment: were you able to try this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [grok debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to debug the grok. Definitely some issues with the code example above.